# Frame and details from SCAPY

Tags: scapy

Wireshark shows Frame details at top of the packet decode.

For example, Frame Number, Frame Length, etc.

How can these details be extracted from a pcap file using SCAPY?

Answer (score 2):

You need to build them (that’s what wireshark does). Those infos are not written in the pcap, they are created while reading

```
packets = rdpcap("path/file.pcapng")
i=0
for p in packets:
    length = len(p)
    i += 1
    print("n%s : Len=%s" % (i, length) )
```

Comment: That is satisfactory answer, can you suggest how to retrieve 'frame.time_relative' from wireshark into pytho using scapy?

Comment: You can do `time_relative = p.time - packets[0].time`

Comment: This does not answer question. Pcap files contain frame information. Yes, frame info was created at capture time by Wireshark, but how do we read that info from a pcap using Scapy? Frame info is not contained in packet data but it is contained in pcap file.